# Progress Dialog is closed when touch on screen

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I use a `ProgressDialog` in the thread. In the `onButtonClick` the thread is started, but when I touch anywhere on the screen the `ProgressDialog` is closed.

How can I prevent this?

```
private void ButtonClick(View view) {

    btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetStudentData();
        }
    });
}

private synchronized void GetStudentData() {  
    try {
        // Thread to display loader
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                dialog = Msg.ShowProgressDialogBox(
                    getActivity(),
                    dialog,
                    "Please wait while we fetch the student data...");
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String studentData="Kailas";
            }   
        }
    } catch(Exception ex {
    }
}
```

**Update**

When I touch on the screen the `ProgressDialog` disappears but get all data.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? How is going your dialog?

Comment: I used dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance()); these code and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private synchronized void GetStudentData() {

    try {
    // Thread to display loader
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            dialog = Msg.ShowProgressDialogBox(getActivity(),
                    dialog,
                    "Please wait while we fetch the student data...");
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance());
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                  String studentData="Kailas";
         }   
    }
}
```

I Have used this line **dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance());** and it worked fine in my **android device OS(4.0.1) also tested on OS(2.6.3)**

Comment: how does this code will understand when data is fetched? and with what argument close the dialog?

Comment: in second thread you you process on your code. then you can close the dialog.

Answer (score 54):

Add this to your dialog:

```
yourDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

In this way you can touch screen and the Dialog will be not canceled.

**EDIT**

If you are using `DialogFragment`, then you must use the following code snippet before calling *show(FragmentManager mng, String tag)*:

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906269/alertdialogs-setcancelablefalse-method-not-working).

```
dialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
```

**EDIT 2**

Be careful with `ProgressDialog` , because with **Android Oreo (v8.0)** it is now deprecated.

Comment: i have used these yourDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); and yourDialog.setCancelable(true); but it not works

Comment: try dialog.setCancelable(false); before Looper.loop();

Comment: @Kailas where do you put the line? I always put this line when i create my Dialog, not on run(){} function.

Comment: @Kailas there is something wrong elsewhere; i would rather use an AsyncTask, where you can create a Dialog and also show() and dismiss() it with onPreExecute() and onPostExecute().

Comment: spot on, solved my problem using `AlertDialog`.  UPVOTED :)

Answer (score 3):

When you are making certain important data downloading process then you can make progress dialog not able to cancel using below code:

```
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
mDialog.setOnCancelListener(new Dialog.OnCancelListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // DO SOME STUFF HERE
    }
}
```

Also you can go for the progress bar in action bar if you are using in your project.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Make a class like this:

```
public class Progresss {

    static ProgressDialog dialog;

    public static void start(Context context) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        try {
            dialog.show();
        } catch (BadTokenException e) {
        }
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog123);
        // dialog.setMessage(Message);
        // return dialog;
    }

    public static void stop() {
        if(dialog!=null)
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

This is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Usage is like this:

```
Progresss.start(context);
Progresss.stop();
```