# Pressing back button on progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, back-button

I have a progress bar in start of one of my activities. I want to be able to press back when it is still processing to go back to my previous activity. I tried setting it setCancelable to true but it will also be dismissed when the user clicks on the screen. I only want the progress bar to be dismissed when the user clicks the back button. There are some topics in sf about this but I couldn't reach what I wanted from any of them.
I'll appreciate if you can help me with this.

Comment: `progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` try this. also add this `setCancelable(true);`

Comment: Thanks @ShabbirDhangot it is by far the best solution, but the best solution would be the one to press back and go to the previous activity and not just dismiss the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss your progress bar on `onBackPressed()`. Try below code:-

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   if(progressBar.isShowing())
   {
       progressBar.dismiss();
   }
}
```

**Note:**

Please remove `setCancelable` true and `progressBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`.

See below link:-

[Progress Dialog is closed when touch on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655715/progress-dialog-is-closed-when-touch-on-screen)

Comment: it doesn't have any effect