# ProgressDialog is not showing circle

Tags: android, fragment, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I have a progressDialog in my fragment. The thing I need is to show little circle. But it is showing only message. It's killing me

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("My message");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Large);
        progressDialog.show();
```

Fragment - method show progress dialog is edited by your help

```
private void loginEmail() {

        showProgressDialog();
        FactoryAPI.getInstanceLogin().login("test@test.cz", "heslo123").enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    user = response.body().getUser();
                    startActivity();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.email_password_is_not_right, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", "error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259506/i-want-a-progress-circle-instead-of-progress-dialog

Comment: Because of this _progressDialog.setMessage("My message");_ message is showing. U can use _ProgressBar_ if u want in circle

Comment: Replace `progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Large);` with `progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);`

Comment: progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER‌​); by default it's already a circle. No need to add this line

Comment: You want to display circular progress with popupDialog or without popupDialog? Please post your fragment code.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try @Stepan

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: [Maybe the color issue, see my unswear here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533325/4148568)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ProgressBar`, not a `ProgressDialog`.
Example:
Put this in your layout file where you want to put the ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar" />
```

Then call `progressBar.setVisiblity(view.visible)` where you want to show it, and hide it when you finish loading what you want.

Comment: While this may be correct, its not a good answer. Try giving some examples.

Comment: @TreviAwater Changed answer.

Comment: I tried ProgressBar but it is old version. I would like to modern version (material design

Comment: @Stepan Please post your full xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Just remove

```
  progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Large);
```

By default the "loading" icon is the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change this line `progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Large)` to `progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER)`

```
private void loginEmail() {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("My message");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();

    FactoryAPI.getInstanceLogin().login("test@test.cz", "heslo123").enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {

            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                 progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                user = response.body().getUser();
                startActivity();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.email_password_is_not_right, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                 progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("error", "error");
        }
    });
}
```

**STYLE_SPINNER** -

> Creates a ProgressDialog with a circular, spinning progress bar.

**STYLE_HORIZONTAL** -

> Creates a ProgressDialog with a horizontal progress bar.

Reference: [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Comment: I have added that line but nothing changed

Comment: thanks, but the circle is there. I do not know what I am doing wrong