# ProgressDialog circle not showing in device

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have this ProgressDialog in my activity. I'm using a few devices to test but only in one the loading circle is not showing.
The device that it's not showing it's a Moto G4 Plus running android 7.0. Below there is a picture.

[image: Moto G4 Plus running android 7.0]

I also run the app in a Asus Zenfone 3 running also android 7.0. They both are running android 7.0 but only one don't show the circle.
[image: Asus Zenfone 3 running android 7.0]

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Carregando...");
   }

    private void myMethod(){
            progressDialog.show();
   }
```

Did anyone had the same problem? Is there a way to solve it and still use the ProgressDialog?

Comment: ProgressDialog is deprecated now. You better use ProgressBar in a Dialog.

Comment: @ShahinMursalov But it is deprecated for android O, right? On android nougat it should work

Comment: yes, that is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether your device is in Power Saving mode (some devices disable animation) or the animation is off in Developer Options.

Comment: It was the animation that was disabled. Tks

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the color of the circle. I ran into the issue that circle by default was white and background of the dialog also was white.

[Here more information how to change the color.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018157/how-to-change-default-progressdialog-circle-color-in-android)