# Android: ProgressDialog Circle not showing

Tags: java, android

I tried to implement a loading circle in my application as it transitioned from the previous activity to this activity. As there are a ton of calculations in this activity, it turns black screen as it's doing the calculations for a good 10 to 15 seconds, once the calculations are done it'd display an image, seen in onCreate: `resultImage.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);`

However, the circle doesn't appear, and it's still the same old black screen to image transition.

**Imported:**

`import android.app.ProgressDialog;`

**Declared:**

`private ProgressDialog progressDialog;`

**Initialized:**

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(null);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

**Made it visible:**

`progressDialog.show();`

**Changed its message as the code progressed:**

`progressDialog.setMessage("Finding Objects...");`

`progressDialog.setMessage("Calculating Areas...");`

`progressDialog.setMessage("Calculating Height...");`

... etc etc

**onCreate:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(null);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_test);



        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d("opencv", "OpenCVLoader.initDebug() - ERROR");
        } else {
            Log.d("opencv", "OpenCVLoader.initDebug() - OK");
        }


        String filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra(FILEPATH);
        ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();

        File dir = new File(filePath);
        File[] listFile;

        listFile = dir.listFiles();

        for (File e : listFile) {
            f.add(e.getAbsolutePath());

        }


        paths = f;


        resetVariables();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Finding Objects...");
        for (int xx = 0; xx < paths.size(); xx++) {
            Bitmap areaBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(paths.get(xx));
            getArea(areaBitmap);

        }
        if (loopCounter > 0) {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Calculating Areas...");
            meanBlackArea = blackArea / loopCounter;

            Log.e("meanBlackArea", "30% of mean black " + String.valueOf(meanBlackArea * 0.3) + " 110% of mean black " + String.valueOf(meanBlackArea * 1.1));
            Log.e("Loopcounter", String.valueOf(loopCounter));
        }
        resetVariables();


        Log.e("~", "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

        Log.e("Lowest Green", String.valueOf(greenArea));
        Log.e("~", "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

        progressDialog.setMessage("Calculating Height...");

        int frameNumber = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < paths.size(); x++) {

            Bitmap calculationsBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(paths.get(x));
            numRectBlack = 0;
            numRectGreen = 0;

            tempBitmap = findCombineBitmap(calculationsBitmap);
            if (check == true) {
                if (Double.isInfinite(tempLineHeightCm) == false) {
                    frameNumber = x;
                    finalBitmap = tempBitmap;
                }
            }

        }
        progressDialog.setMessage("Tidying Up...");
        TextView tvR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvR);
        if(tempLineHeightCm==0) {
            tvR.setText("We could not detect a bounce!\nPlease do the following and try again:\n1. Remove all foreign objects from testing grounds.\n2.Make sure that there are ample lighting on the testing grounds.");
        }else{
            tvR.setText("Frame " + frameNumber + ", Bounce Height = " + tempLineHeightCm + "cm");

            ImageView resultImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resultImage);

            resultImage.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

**Link to code file:**

[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8Kt9KpV9HnRMXJ4SFY0WXltSm8?usp=sharing)

Notes:

1. MainActivity.java has a working progresscircle
2. TestAutoRun.java is the one I'm working on.

Comment: [Maybe the color issue, see my unswear here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533325/4148568)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show `ProgressDialog`, start new `AsyncTask` and do your heavy calculations in background. After the `AsyncTask` completes, hide the progress dialog and go to next activity.

If you don't know how to use `AsyncTask`, check the reference [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)